# How to reinstall IOS Simulator

Tags: xcode6, ios-simulator

I have installed xCode 6.1.1 (latest update) with the Mac OS X 10.10 Seed 2 (10.10.2)

When i run my IOS app on any simulator type (5,5S, 6 and etc.),
I have a black flashing on the IOS Simulator.

I want to try Remove the simulator and reinstall it again.

How can i do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Xcode 6 you can simply go to Menu > Window > Devices > Simulators and delete a simulator you don't need.

Comment: What if you can't do that? I went to the Devices window and tried to create a simulator, but when I press the "Create" button, nothing happens :(

Answer (score 3):

Have you done a reset on the Simulator first?  iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings